# Version of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let $f \in L_{\mathbb{R}^+}^1(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\lambda).$ We want to prove the following version of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma: $$\lim_{y \to +\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\sin(yx)dx=0.$$

**Hint:** consider the sequence of functions $f_n=\min(f,n)1_{[-n\pi;n\pi]}.$

Let $\phi_n=\min(f,n).$

For all $n \in \mathbb{N},y>0$
$$|\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\sin(yx)|dx \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_n(x)-f(x)|dx+|\int_{-n\pi}^{n\pi}\phi_n\sin(yx)dx|$$
then we take $\limsup_{y}$ and then we let $n \to +\infty,$ after noticing that $\lim_n\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_n(x)-f(x)|dx=0$ from the dominated convergence theorem.

So it remains to prove that for a fixed $n \in \mathbb{N},$ $\lim_{y \to+\infty}\int_{-n\pi}^{n\pi}\phi_n(x)\sin(yx)dx=0$

The following argument, is it true?
$$\int_{-n\pi}^{n\pi}\phi_n(x)\sin(yx)dx=\frac{1}{y}\int_{-n \pi y}^{n\pi y}\phi_n(\frac{x}{y})\sin(x)dx$$
So, $$|\int_{-n\pi}^{n\pi}\phi_n(x)\sin(yx)dx| \leq \frac{1}{y} (\int_{-n \pi y}^{-[ny]\pi}ndx +\int_{[ny] \pi}^{ny \pi}ndx+|\int_{-[n y] \pi}^{[ny] \pi}\phi_n(\frac{x}{y})\sin(x)dx|)$$

which implies

$|\int_{-n\pi}^{n\pi}\phi_n(x)\sin(yx)dx| \leq \frac{2n \pi}{y}+\frac{1}{y}|\sum_{k=0}^{[ny]-1}(-1)^k\int_0^{\pi}\sin(x)(\phi_n(\frac{x-k\pi}{y})-\phi_n(-\frac{x-k \pi}{y}))dx|,$

we conclude,

$|\int_{-n\pi}^{n\pi}\phi_n(x)\sin(yx)dx| \leq \frac{2 \pi n}{y}+\frac{2 \pi n}{y}|\sum_{k=0}^{[ny]-1}(-1)^k| \leq \frac{4 \pi n}{y} \rightarrow_{y \to +\infty}0.$

Comment: My gutt-feel tells me that this won't work.

Comment: Note that your integral is equivalent to $$ -\frac{1}{y}\left[\phi_{n}(x) \cos(yx) \right]_{-y\pi}^{y\pi} + \frac{1}{y}\int_{-y\pi}^{y\pi} \phi′_{n}(x) \cos(yx) d x$$

Comment: We cannot use integration by part, $\phi_n$ doesn't have to be differentiable

Comment: This is my favorite lemma in real analysis, tell me are we allowed to use complex numbers?

Comment: Of course by taking the positive and the negative part, we have $\lim_{y \to +\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)e^{ixy}dx=0,$ so yeh, if there is a way without taking the positive and negative part

Answer (score 0):

First consider case when f is constant on an interval [a,b] and 0 outside of it.
This is an easy computation.
Then consider a case when f is a finite sum of function constant on disjoint intervals.
It just directly follows from the first case and property of limits.
Next, consider a case of f continuous with compact support.
This function can be uniformly approximated by functions from step two.
Lastly, integrable functions can be approximated (in L1 norm) by continuous functions with compact support.

Comment: your way is another approach, the objective was to prove it without using the density in $L^1$